# Looking for a Cellular network environment or Heteregenous wireless networks environment Datasets

Tags: data-request, large-datasets

I am looking for a Cellular network environment or Heterogeneous wireless networks environment Dataset. A dataset that includes network parameters as features such as delay, jitter, throughput, cost fo network ...etc.